# Use specific SSH keys for specific servers only

Tags: ssh, privacy

When using SSH key authentication, all available keys are tried against the server. Is there a possibility to set some SSH keys in a way, so that they are only disclosed to a given remote server list, for privacy?

I've been looking but wasn't able to find any information or documentation regarding this at all. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `.ssh` directory you can create `config` and set inside specific keys for specific hosts:

```
Host h1
    HostName 192.168.1.10
    IdentityFile /path/to/ssh/key/h1.key

Host h2
    HostName 192.168.1.11
    IdentityFile /path/to/ssh/key/h2.key
```

If the directory with these keys is not `.ssh` they will not be tried when access host not in `config` file